# How to pass data between view controller and the tab-bar's view controllers using segue?

Tags: swift, swift5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXkuM.png)

I aslo added the screenshot of the design.

I'm having a one  viewcontrollerA and a  tabbar with 2 view controller B,C.

I want to pass the data of `data` variable   from  VcA -> VcB via tabbar.

I have  dragged the segue from `submitbutton` to the `TabBar`.

I tried to pass the data with segue

So, please help  me out from this.

```
//In  View controller A
class ViewControllerA : UIViewController{
var data : String = ""
    @IBAction func submitButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {   
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "homePage", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![0] as! ViewControllerB

     vc.containsData = data

    }

}
```

```
//In Tabbar View controller B
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    var containsData : String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    print(containsData)

    }
}
```

In Tab bar's viewcontrollerB I just printed the var "data" in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer

```
    @IBAction func submitButonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "homePage", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let destinationViewController = barViewControllers.viewControllers![0] as! ViewControllerB
        destinationViewController.containsData = Data
    }
```

Comment: Great you get it fixed. Please always try to include all the related code to reproduce the issues for better help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in to the code, i figured out the issues.

First you need to use `prepare(for segue` method to pass data as your are presenting `viewControllerb` using segue. So, in your `ViewController`, add this method and set data for `ViewControllerb` as below,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let tabController = segue.destination as? UITabBarController {
        let bController = tabController.children.first(where: { $0 is ViewControllerb })
        (bController as? ViewControllerb)?.containsData = self.stringTF.text!
    }
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
}
```

Second, remove method `submitButtonTapped` from `ViewController` because you are presenting ViewControllerb using segue so this is not required. Also remove this method outlet in the storyboard by clicking cross as shown in the below image

[image]

Comment: as you are printing ```print(vcA.data)``` I'm not able to print

Comment: I have shown the code which I tried and a screenshot of the design

Comment: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.                                 I'm getting the error

Comment: I think you have multiple issues. It would be better if you can share sample project with the problem so that it can save time to fix the issue.

Comment: I have the example here in GitHub https://github.com/patelFab/TabbarDemo

Comment: Done....Now  please check https://github.com/patelFab/TabbarDemo

Comment: @PatelFab I updated the answer. Please follow the steps to fix the issues.

Comment: Ok sir I'm trying this and then I'll let you know

Comment: If remove method ```submitButtonTapped``` it won't work.

Comment: Sir you do change the code on my GitHub then it will be a great help... Coz as above you explained I'm still confused

Comment: Actually the project wasn't uploaded properly but looking at the code i figured out the issues. When you remove `submitButtonTapped` what happens? Does it crash or compile errors? I can update on git if i get a working copy.

Comment: while removing ```submitButtonTapped``` I'm not able  to open the Viewcontrollerb

Comment: Sorry, i won't be able to help as it seems you have different code than the shared one.

Comment: No , I have the same code that I shared with u....If its possible , can u change the code in project so that I can re-download the project and check it ...what mistake I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

If you are pass data viewController -> Tabcontroller using NavigationController. please try blow code on button/ tableviewCell/ collectionViewCell Click/ Press

---

```
let navController = self.Your_TABBAR_CONTROLLER.viewControllers![Tab_Index] as! UINavigationController
let vc = navController.topViewController as! Your_View_Controller
vc.name = Data
```

---

```
let navController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
let vc = navController.topViewController as! HomeViewController
vc.name= self.name
```

Comment: I want the data from the different ViewController. to the tabbbar's viewcontroller.....

Comment: this might helpful while passing data between ViewControllers in Tabbar